# SharePoint Silverlight Document Viewer Webpart?

Tags: web-part, silverlight

SharePoint Silverlight Word Document Viewer Webpart?

Please help me as I need it in my project urgently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that i know of that handles ms docs in silverligt is textglow:

http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/displaying-ms-word-files-in-sharepoint.html

hope it helps :)

Comment: i tried but it not works. thanks